# How to integrate Zoho CRM with Messagebird

Tags: integration, zoho, messagebird

I am trying to authenticate to messagebird using a custom function of zoho CRM. I am trying the following script:

```
//HEADER

API_Key = "***"; I am hiding the API Key
HeaderMap = Map();
HeaderMap.put("Content-Type","application/json");
HeaderMap.put("Authorization","Access Key " + API_Key);
ENDPOINT = "https://conversations.messagebird.com/v1/send";
Request = invokeurl
[
    url :ENDPOINT
    type :POST
    headers:HeaderMap
];
```

I am getting this error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":2,"description":"Request was not authenticated"}]}
```

and i am passing this json:

```
{"Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Access Key ***"}
```

Does any one if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Hi the authorization header has to be of the form `-H 'Authorization: AccessKey KEY'`

Answer (score 4):

AccessKey should be in one word

```
HeaderMap.put("Authorization","AccessKey" + API_Key);
```

Extract from my FlowBuilder example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

worth noting that the webhook related APIs only work with LIVE API keys. I didn't see any mention of that anywhere in the docs, but it only worked for me after trying with a live key... I hope this will save someone some time!